# How to search datetime index and place None-values to another variables whenever it is weekend Python

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Say that I have a pandas `df` which contains financial time-series data with datetime index. An example:

```
x = ['10-06-2016', '10-07-2016', '10-10-2016', '10-11-2016', '10-12-2016'] 
y = [0,1,2,3,4]
```

Note that I don't have time-series values on weekends, which is why '10-08-2016' and '10-09-2016' are not printed on dataframe index.

I wish to create a new `y` vector which places `None` in spots where weekends are.

So ideal output:

```
x = ['10-06-2016', '10-07-2016', '10-08-2016', '10-09-2016', '10-10-2016', '10-11-2016', '10-12-2016']
y = [0,1,None,None,2,3,4]
```

What's the best way to accomplish this? Since `x` is not printing the weekends, how do I search `x` is weekend and then insert `None` values to `y`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `reindex` the data frame which has a `datetimeIndex` with a wider range of date as follows, missing values will be filled with `NaN`:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'Value': y}, index=pd.to_datetime(x))

#       Value
#2016-10-06 0
#2016-10-07 1
#2016-10-10 2
#2016-10-11 3
#2016-10-12 4

df.reindex(pd.date_range(start = df.index.min(), end = df.index.max()))

#         Value
#2016-10-06 0.0
#2016-10-07 1.0
#2016-10-08 NaN
#2016-10-09 NaN
#2016-10-10 2.0
#2016-10-11 3.0
#2016-10-12 4.0
```

Comment: Do you know how to reindex taking into account the time component? In my real data I have date and time for datetime index. I used your method which creates nan values but it also only shows me one data point per day.

Comment: You can specify the `freq` parameter in the `pd.date_range()` function. For example, if you have hourly data, you can do `df.reindex(pd.date_range(start = df.index.min(), end = df.index.max(), freq="H"))`, etc.